# I accidentally retracted my flag. How can I put it back?

Tags: support, flags

Original Question asked: [Is there a way to make a piston push a block and make it into an item?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/359785/is-there-a-way-to-make-a-piston-push-a-block-and-make-it-into-an-item/359967#359967)

Possible duplicate:[How can I make an automatic cobblestone breaker?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/217457/how-can-i-make-an-automatic-cobblestone-breaker)

Is there still a way to alert the duplicate to an admin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you think it's unlikely that other community members will see it and vote as duplicate, you can use the 'custom' flag feature to alert the mod team. In the text box, explain the situation (that you accidentally retracted the flag but still think it's a duplicate) and we'll look at it.

In regards to your example - the question OP appears to be using a different version of Minecraft to the duplicate target. I have edited the question to make this clearer.